# Factoring quadratic equations

Tags: factoring, quadratics

During the video on the link (at 20 seconds) the narrator says that $(x^2+3)$ cannot be factored, however I believe that it can be factored to $(x-1)(x-3)$

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IeZkmO0STg

There must be something missing in my understanding of this as I'm assuming the narrator is not incorrect,

If anyone could explain why this cannot be factored I would be very grateful.

-Connor

Comment: $(x-1)(x-3)=x^2-4x+3$. See [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1%29%28x-3%29).

Comment: Try expanding $(x-1)(x-3)$.  You get $(x^2-4x+3)\neq (x^2+3)$.  As for *why* it cannot be factored, see [Eisenstein's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion)

Comment: That makes sense, however another example I have is $(x^2-9)$ factors to $(x+3)(x-3)$ , I do not understand why the method does not work for the original equation

Comment: @FlewittConnor Because $x^2-9$ has a minus sign instead of a plus sign. You could however write it using complex numbers: $x^2+3=\left(x+\sqrt{-3}\right)\left(x-\sqrt{-3}\right)$.

Comment: @FlewittConnor, $x^2 +3$ cannot be written as $a^2 - b^2$ which factorises into $(a+b)(a-b)$. On the other hand, $x^2 -9 = (x-3)(x+3)$.

Comment: Have you at least seen the quadratic formula for finding the roots?  We can factor it, but not with rational coefficients (by eisenstein's).  You could find the two roots as $x_{1,2} = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.  In the case of $x^2-9$, if you plug those numbers in, you get $\frac{-0\pm\sqrt{0+4\cdot 1\cdot 9}}{2\cdot 1} = \frac{\pm 6}{2}=\pm 3$ as the roots.  In the case of $x^2+3$ the roots would be $\frac{\pm\sqrt{-12}}{2}$ and so factor as $(x+\sqrt{-3})(x-\sqrt{-3})$, but that is neither rational, nor real, and so doesn't usually fit the meaning of "factoring."

Comment: @JMoravitz I have briefly touched on the quadratic formula for finding roots, thank you I now see by using this formula I can find out if my roots can be used for factorisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roots are the values of X that makes entire LHS to be zero. In your case LHS is absent so if LHS is as you provided & if RHS is zero then 
$X^2 = -3$
So $X = \sqrt{-3}$
Meaning roots are imaginary or does not exists